# Why doesn't AppMaker image widget accept camera snapshot when HTML image element will?

Tags: javascript, html, google-app-maker

This code works fine if I use an HTML image in place of AppMaker widget ‘snapshot’.
Does all but put the image in the AppMaker image widget when is use the AppMaker widget.

```
//HTML at startup
<video id="stream"top="0" left="0"width="400" height="532"</video>
<canvas id="capture" width="200" height="266" ></canvas>

//Starts the video stream on-click the AppMaker image widget ‘snapshot’
var capture = document.getElementById( "capture" );
var stream =document.getElementById('stream');
var cameraStream = null;
function startStreaming() {
 var mediaSupport = 'mediaDevices' in navigator;
 if( mediaSupport && null == cameraStream ) {
       navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia( { video: true } )
       .then( function( mediaStream ) {
           stream.srcObject = mediaStream;
           stream.play();
       })
       .catch( function( err ) {
           console.log( "Unable to access camera: " + err );
       });
   }
   else {
       alert( 'Your browser does not support media devices.' );
       return;
   }
}
startStreaming(); // displays the camera output in the video window
```

captures a photo of the video stream
'snapshot' is an App Maker image widget

```
//shutter button on-click script
var capture =document.getElementById('capture');
var stream=document.getElementById("stream");

function captureSnapshot() {  
   var ctx = capture.getContext('2d');
   ctx.drawImage( stream, 0, 0, capture.width, capture.height );
   document.getElementById('snapshot').src=capture.toDataURL("image/png" );
{
captureSnapshot;
```

Comment: If you only named an App Maker widget 'snapshot' and then try to reference that widget by using getElementById() then it does not find that widget in the DOM because app maker widgets don't have an id attribute unless you added that attribute via code. This is an assumption, but I believe AM uses getElementsByClassName()[0], which is why widget names on any given page have to be unique. Don't know for sure that this is your problem though.

Comment: var imageWidgets=document.getElementsByClassName("image");
    //alert ("number of image widgets="+imageWidgets.length); returns 0 ;

Comment: How do I add app Maker widget 'id' in HTML?

Comment: You would use `widget.getElement().setAttribute('id', 'snapshot')`. I have not experimented around with this but I'm not sure if an image widget specifically can accept a DataURL like you are assigning here. I know that it is possible in an html widget that has an <img> tag as you described, you may want to try this in your captureSnapshot function `app.pages.Yourpage.descendants.YourImgWidget.url = capture.toDataURL('image/png')`. If that doesn't work then it might be a restriction on the image widget.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: app.pages... worked. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Could you point me at a finger signature code that lends itself to app Maker?